# MySQL update bigint field

Tags: mysql, sql, database, bigint

How do you update a MySql database bigint field?

Currently our database has a bigint(196605) field which is generating errors. I am pretty sure the field limit is 250 i.e. bigint(250) which explains the errors being generated.

The field itself only stores integer values 3 digits e.g. 100, so I am not sure why it is even bigint. In any case, I need to fix the field without any loss of data.

Any help would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common confusion ... `BIGINT` type has a **fixed size** is stored on **8B** so the **ONLY** difference between `BIGINT(1)` and `BIGINT(20`) is the number of digits that is gonna be displayed 1 digit respectively 20 digits .

If you store only 3 digits numbers ,and you do not think you will need more you can use a `SMALLINT UNSIGNED` type which takes only **2B** instead of **8B** so you will save a lot of space and the performance will increase.

I suggest you read [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html) first.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that, bigint(196605) is definitely too big and I'm pretty sure is not valid i.e. the max size is bigint(250) but I am not sure how to update the field to reduce the value.

Comment: `ALTER TABLE <table_name> MODIFY <col_name> SMALLINT UNSIGNED;` since you are storing 3 digit numbers

Comment: Thanks, this is just what I needed. Will the column data be lost if the field type is changed from BIGINT to SMALLINT?

Comment: Not if the values in that column do not exceed the limit of `SMALLINT` which is 65535 (unsigned)

Comment: I'm getting error #1347 - '<database_name>.<table_name>' is not BASE TABLE

Comment: <database_name> should be replaced with the name of your database and <table_name> should be replace with your table name . i've put it like this because i do not know your db name or table name

Comment: Yep, understood that and I did the same thing, replaced the actual names with <substitute>. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Turns out our database had other problems. Although I was never actually able see this through and resolve this problem properly I am 99.9% sure your solution is correct. Thanks for you help

Comment: np, let me know if this solution worked out for you :) cheers

Answer (score 0):

May be when creating database field, you set its length, if we do not set any length then I think it takes 11 as default. but If we pass then it will take specified value as length.

Answer (score 0):

Before you do something, export (backup) your data into an SQL file (autogenerated inserts for your data) to save your data before you change your table and you know that if your data is lost, you can import it.

If you want to change your column, you must update your table like this:

`ALTER TABLE tableName CHANGE columnName newColumnName BIGINT(250);`

I think this should work.

**DIDN'T TESTED** (I use MS SQL Server 2008 and can't check if it works)